# Convert keyboard azerty to qwerty and vice-versa

Tags: python, keyboard

Is there a module for converting the letters of a **AZERTY** keyboard in a **QWERTY** keyboard letters and **vice versa**?

To do this it must also be able to detect the keyboard type, is it possible?

*Example:* 'data'. to_qwerty () -> 'dqtq' **or** 'dqtq'. to_azerty () -> 'data'

Or a **simple** solution without having to type all the letters of each letter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to know the actual keyboard type. If the keyboard type is set correctly, you'll get the correct letters. So you would only ever need to do this if the keyboard type is set wrongly, but the user didn't notice. Seems unlikely :-)

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes it is not wrong, I'm looking just to translate the letters, for example ,wqi (azerty) = mzai (qwerty), I thought I need to detect the keyboard type, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to convert one string to another, that's pretty simple:
(it does however require you to specify how they translate from one to the other)

```
>>> translate_dict = dict(zip("abcdef", "123456"))
>>> translate_this = "deadbeef"
>>> ''.join([translate_dict.get(x) for x in translate_this])
'45142556'
```

or

```
>>> ''.join(map(translate_dict.get, translate_this))
'45142556'
```

... or any number of ways to do this in a few lines.

If you want to get fancy and do something similar to what you did in your question (call a method on a string and have it converted) then you can have a look at the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) module that will let you do that. Takes a bit more work, but you would be able to do something like this

```
>>> mystring.encode('qwerty')
```

The big effort is probably getting the data on how to translate everything.

The easiest thing is probably to make sure you have the right keymap before starting to type. :)